# Django ForeignKey with default -- App registry isn't ready

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, default

I have the following code:

```
class A(models.Model):
  foo = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
  class Meta:
    get_latest_by = 'foo'


class B(models.Model):
  bar = models.ForeignKey(A, default=A.objects.latest())
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#latest) this is the way to go including a default with the latest object of a different model.

Whether I am trying to run the application (`python manage.py runserver`) or do a migration (`python manage.py makemigrations`) I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bla/workspace/foobar/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 427, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 391, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 106, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 190, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/bla/workspace/foobar/b/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    class B(models.Model):
  File "/home/bla/workspace/foobar/b/models.py", line 54, in B
    bar = models.ForeignKey(A, blank=True, null=True, default=A.objects.latest()) # @UndefinedVariable
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 497, in latest
    return self._earliest_or_latest(field_name=field_name, direction="-")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 491, in _earliest_or_latest
    return obj.get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 346, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 122, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 963, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 694, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 769, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 100, in as_sql
    ordering, o_params, ordering_group_by = self.get_ordering()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 424, in get_ordering
    self.query.get_meta(), default_order=asc):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 460, in find_ordering_name
    field, targets, alias, joins, path, opts = self._setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 492, in _setup_joins
    pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1416, in setup_joins
    names, opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1336, in names_to_path
    field, model, direct, m2m = opts.get_field_by_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 415, in get_field_by_name
    cache = self.init_name_map()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 444, in init_name_map
    for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 560, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
    cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 574, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
    for klass in self.apps.get_models():
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 156, in get_models
    self.check_ready()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 119, in check_ready
    raise RuntimeError("App registry isn't ready yet.")
RuntimeError: App registry isn't ready yet.
```

My settings file includes both Apps (A and B) in INSTALLED_APPS.

I am using Django version 1.7a2.
Again the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#app-loading-changes) has something on this error:
`RuntimeError: App registry isn't ready yet. This happens when importing an application configuration or a models module triggers code that depends on the app registry.`

But I can't figure out how to apply it accordingly to my model.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to think django first validates model classes and only then allows you to hit database for values.

Also note, that code in your example means that by default you'll get latest A value at the application start moment. No matter what new A records will you add then - default bar are  binded to this old value.

If you want a dynamic lookup for the latest A (and I think you are), you shoud pass a callable instead of value.

try to replace bar with this (note parenthesis removed):

```
bar = models.ForeignKey(A, default=A.objects.latest)
```

I dont know exactly if there are "objects" member in A already when B are created, so I would recomend you more verbose but reliable way:

```
def latest_A():
    return A.objects.latest()

class B(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(A, default=latest_A)
```

To see the difference, your code equivalent is like this:

```
latest_A_on_start = A.objects.latest() # got it only once

class B(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(A, default=latest_A_on_start) #it s just "static" value
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by: `No matter what new A records will you add then - default bar are binded to this old value.`?
For example I add a new B; the default will be The latest A. After that I add a new A and afterwards again a new B. The second B will have a different default value as the first one; right?

Comment: no, for your code they will be same, cause function call operator just  will be replaced with calculated value on start. See my new edits